# Cannot select tr not containing th elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The example is from a book.
Table heading,Odd,even rows have different colors.
It selects tr which do not contain th element so that prevent the style overlapping between table heading and even row.
But after the rending of browser,it will comes out `<tr class="table-heading even">`.
So the style of even rows overwrite that of table heading row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Styling Alternate Rows</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .table-heading{
          text-align:left;
          background-color:#6C6; /*green for table heading*/
      }     
      .odd{
          background-color:#ffc; /*pale yellow for odd row*/
      }
      .even{
          background-color:#cef; /*pale blue for even rows*/
      }
      .highlight{
          font-weight:bolid;
          color:#f00;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function (){
              //style table heading row
              $('th').parent().addClass('table-heading');             
              //style odd row
              $('tr:not([th]):odd').addClass('odd');
              //style even row
              $('tr:not([th]):even').addClass('even');
              //style next table cells of the cell containing the word "Henry"
              $('td:contains("Henry")').next().addClass('highlight');
          }
      );
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>As your like it</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>All well</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Henry IV Part 1</td>
            <td>Tragely</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Henry V</td>
            <td>Tragely</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, put the table-heading rule at the bottom to override .even

```
  .odd{
      background-color:#ffc; /*pale yellow for odd row*/
  }
  .even{
      background-color:#cef; /*pale blue for even rows*/
  }
  .highlight{
      font-weight:bolid;
      color:#f00;
  }
  .table-heading{
      text-align:left;
      background-color:#6C6; /*green for table heading*/
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `:has` selector, try this:

```
$('tr:not(":has(th)"):odd').addClass('odd');
$('tr:not(":has(th)"):even').addClass('even');
```

Or:

```
var $tr = $('tr:not(":has(th)")');
$tr.filter(':odd').addClass('odd')
$tr.filter(':even').addClass('even')
```

Comment: Nice :) It works.
jQuery does not support XPath selector anymore ??

Comment: @user1022209 jQuery supports XPath selectors. your `not` selector doesn't exclude the elements properly :)

Answer (score 1):

just remove the unwanted class http://jsfiddle.net/8GHKd/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
          //style odd row
          $('tr:not([th]):odd').addClass('odd');
          //style even row
          $('tr:not([th]):even').addClass('even');
          //style next table cells of the cell containing the word "Henry"
          $('td:contains("Henry")').next().addClass('highlight');
          //style table heading row
          $('th').parent().addClass('table-heading').removeClass('even');
      }
  );​
```

Answer (score 1):

use not() to filter tr th out

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $th = $('th');
    //style table heading row
    $th.parent().addClass('table-heading');
    //style odd row
    $('tr:odd').not($th.parent()).addClass('odd');
    //style even row
    $('tr:even').not($th.parent()).addClass('even');
    //style next table cells of the cell containing the word "Henry"
    $('td:contains("Henry")').next().addClass('highlight');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/ELJpN/

or even shorter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $thp = $('th').parent();
    $thp.addClass('table-heading');
    $('tr').not($thp).addClass(function(){
        return $(this).index() % 2 == 0 ? 'even':'odd';
    });    
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/GHGQB/